# What's the best column type for Google+ User ID?

Tags: mysql, google-plus

Google+ has very long User IDs

104560124403688998123

(21 characters), which is not possible to input into BIGINT field (not unsigned)

What column type would you use for such IDs ?

I do not think that varchar is good idea

Answer (score 20, accepted):

if the length of the google id is predictable, use a static `char(length)`, add an index on it and create an (internal) integer primary key. Inside of your application you map the data to the integer primary key. So if someone searches by google id, you lookup the integer primary key for this google id and do the rest of your queries with the integer primary key.

So the schema looks like:

Mapping Table:

```
id (integer) | google_id (char(length))
```

So if you create another table like comments etc, use the primary key `id`, if you want to lookup all comments for a certain googleid, get the internal id first and then join the comments. This way you have only one query criteria on a static, indexed char field with a predictable length, all other joins and queries will use the integer key.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't the mapping table overflow after id reached a limit? That what option we will left?

Comment: hi, there is only one row in the mapping table for each unique google_id, assuming he's using mysql with an unsigned int field the limit would be 4294967295. If that is not enough you could still switch to bigint or use a composite primary key. A table size overflow is not very likely to happen as MySQL is able to store data in the TB range.

Comment: Nice! Make sure there is no varchar or text column in this mapping table because doing so would set the whole row to a variable length, which would end up defeating the purpose of using char for performance boost.

Answer (score 6):

I would use the same as I do with Facebook: **varchar**.

Comment: It's bad when searching. Int columns are great for WHERE clause but I think varchar isn't

Comment: @genesis, I'm not sure about 'int being great' but anything that could break at any time is much bad!

Answer (score 5):

I cannot find official recommendation from google but i use of **decimal 21,0** works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

in python on appengine I save data with ndb.StringProperty and validate with a regex \d{15} hence giving a little margin. it would be really great to know what it the REAL regex to validate this field

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a `VARCHAR(255)` (a variable length string up to 255 characters). The reason is because the id could be a ASCII string that is up to 255 chars long, see reference below.


[Google OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect)

"Authenticating the user involves obtaining an ID token and validating it. ID tokens are a standardized feature of OpenID Connect designed for use in sharing identity assertions on the Internet."

[OpenID Connect Core 1.0 incorporating errata set 1](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)

**sub:** (is the google id)

"REQUIRED. Subject Identifier. A locally unique and never reassigned identifier within the Issuer for the End-User, which is intended to be consumed by the Client, e.g., 24400320 or AItOawmwtWwcT0k51BayewNvutrJUqsvl6qs7A4. It MUST NOT exceed 255 ASCII characters in length. The sub value is a case sensitive string."

Comment: Indeed, also `rfc7519` `section-4.1.2` says, quote: 'The "sub" value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI value'.